# need help with download

Tags: networking, downloads

is there a way to download ubuntu desktop from different regions? I am in US West and on average I get 100MB download speed. ubuntu is stuck downloading at ~40kbps and I don't want to wait 19 hours just to download it again. I have tried different browsers with same result. checked internet on other downloads no issues there.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors

Comment: are these ubuntu desktop 18.04?

Comment: They mirror all the official images.

Comment: yes but what version are these outdated

Comment: Open a mirror's page and find out.

Comment: This doesn't apply to ISO images, but can provide a clue as to up-to-date mirrors are https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors .   If you already have an Ubuntu ISO image, using a `zsync` file may be worthwhile, eg. I wanted a xubuntu iso, but already had an lubuntu iso image, so I zsync'd using the lubuntu iso as my start & download started at ~48% complete (ie. ~half already downloaded) for the cost of an extra ~3M zsync file; ie. saved >600mb of download  (saving will vary on what you start with of course)

Comment: How are you connected? If by WiFi, check your `MTU`. `ifconfig -a | grep -Eo 'MTU:[0-9]+|^[^ ]+'` will show the `MTU`s of each interface.